# CursorAdapter: Should I pass the column name in the constructor?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-adapter

I've created a subclass of CursorAdapter which is used to display 4 separate lists of data in my application.

Each list uses a different column from the database. My question is, how should I tell the adapter which column to use?

In the 2 brief examples below, which would be considered the better practice:

### Option 1

- Pass the column name to the constructor of my adapter.
- This means the fragment will need to know the name of the column.

-

```
// In my fragment:
DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
Cursor cursor = helper.getTitleCursor();
adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(getActivity(), cursor, DBHelper.COL_TITLE);


// The constructor of my CursorAdapter:
public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, String colName) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.displayColumn = colName;
}


// In my cursor adapter:
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_title);

    String titleText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(displayColumn));
    title.setText(titleText);
}
```

### Option 2

- When creating the cursor, use `AS` to give the column a specific name.
- This means the fragment doesn't need to know the name of the column, though I'm not sure it's a better solution.

_

```
// In my DB Helper
public Cursor getTitleCursor() {
    String query = "SELECT title AS displayCol FROM myTable"
    return db.rawQuery(query, null);
}


// In my DB Helper
public Cursor getGenreCursor() {
    String query = "SELECT genre AS displayCol FROM myTable"
    return db.rawQuery(query, null);
}


// In my fragment:
DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
Cursor cursor = helper.getTitleCursor();
adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);


// The constructor of my CursorAdapter:
public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


// In my cursor adapter
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_title);

    String titleText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("displayCol"));
    title.setText(titleText);
}
```

Comment: The Android framework requires a column named `_id` for some cursors. But what exactly do you mean with "better"?

Comment: @CL That's exactly what made me question it-- the CursorAdapter class (i.e. the parent class) requires you pass a column named `_id`. By "better" I mean, is there any obvious reason to use one option over other?